# Correct terminology for Array functions on own line

Tags: javascript, terminology

I'm having a hard time trying to find the right term for a function like:

```
var array = [1, 2, 3];

array.pop();

return array; // returns [1, 2];
```

And:

```
var array = [1, 2, 3].pop();

return array; // returns 3
```

I personally just call the first example "Indirect" because you are indirectly triggering the function on the array and modifying it.

The second example I call, you guessed it, "Direct" because you are directly chaining the function to the array.

Sounds kinda silly, I know.

However, I am very well interested in the actual terminology for these specific pieces of code, if there is one.

Comment: Is your question about the terminology for invoking a method on a variable that points to an object as opposed to invoking the method directly on the object itself? Your question's a little confusing because your two examples are doing slightly different things but I don't think that's what the question is about. A minor point: `array` actually returns `3` in your second example.

Comment: The examples aren't equivalent though, and the second variable "array" is incorrectly named; it's the last element that is returned by `pop()`. Because of that, the second example's array has no named references to it; it is "anonymous" (in a manner of speaking).

Answer (score 1):

In the second case you're doing:

```
[1,2,3].pop();
```

In the first case you're doing:

```
var array = [1, 2, 3];
array.pop();
```

This is simply called variable assignment.

What is creating some confusion in your question is that in the second example you assign the value 3 to a variable called "array", which should really be called something else.